# add read more TextView on another TextView android

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I want to add a simply "Read more" / "Read less" Button on an existing TextView combinating another..

I did this:

```
 this.announcer_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.announcer_description);
    this.readmore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readmore);
    this.readmore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (readmore.getText().equals("Read More"))
                {
                    announcer_description.setText("");
                    announcer_description.setText(currentAnnouncer.getDescription_fr());
                    readmore.setText("");
                    readmore.append("Read less");
                }
                else if (readmore.getText().equals("Read less"))
                {
                    announcer_description.setText("");
                    announcer_description.setText(shortDesc);
                    readmore.setText("");
                    readmore.append("Read more");
                }
            }});
```

My "announcer_description" TextView is initialize to "Read more".. but this doesn't work..
The only way I found using Read more and Read Less is to nest some many OnClickListener in this OnClickListener..

Someone does have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `"Read More"` does not equal `"Read more"`, there is a capitalization difference, so your code is never executed.

You should set values that don't change, like `"Read More"`, in a String to help prevent these types of mistakes, preferably in `strings.xml`.

Create a class wide variable, set it in `onCreate()`:

```
String readMoreString;
...
readMoreString = getResources().getText(R.string.read_more);
```

A simplified OnClickListener:

```
this.readmore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (readmore.getText().toString().equals(readMoreString))
        {
            announcer_description.setText(currentAnnouncer.getDescription_fr());
            readmore.setText(readLessString);
        }
        else 
        {
            announcer_description.setText(shortDesc);
            readmore.setText(readMoreString);
        }
    }
});
```

Also notice how I remove the redundant calls to `setText()`, you don't need to "clear" a previous TextView with `setText("")`.

Comment: I just changes these strings for this forum and it wasn't that ^^ I just used append() and it didn't work .. I just had to make a simple setText OnClick has you shown me.. !! TY

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use this in Recycler view and was facing issues, this library solved my issues.

https://github.com/giangpham96/ExpandableTextView